# Can I download an upcoming game and then activate it on the release date?

Tags: steam, civilization-5

I want to be able to play Civilization 5 on the release date, but I know that it will be at least a 4-5 GB download, so I worry that if I buy a digital copy, the high number of users hitting the distributor's servers will slow downloads to a crawl. If it's possible, I'd like to download the game in advance, so that on release day, I would only be getting a tiny activation key instead of a huge installer.

The game is available for preorder on both [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/8930/) and [Direct2Drive](http://www.direct2drive.com/9611/product/), but neither product page seems to mention what I'm looking for, and I don't know what it's called, so it's hard to search for. Do either of them offer this service?

Comment: People curious why the tags appear to answer half my question can check the [edit history](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/7482/revisions).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This depends entirely on the game. Steam refers to this practice as 'pre-loading' and they do it for select titles. In the specific case of [Civ V](http://store.steampowered.com/news/4346/), yes, you can preload. For other titles, you can check that games respective forums at the Steam community site to get the answer in most cases.

Answer (score 11):

As far as i know [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/news/4346/)  is already pre-loading this game, however not all games can be pre-loaded on Steam.